# HTTP 2.0 Over the Wire (Raw)

Tags: fiddler, wireshark, http2

Are there any tools to see what is coming through the wire (Raw request and response) for HTTP 2.0?
I used Fiddler and saw only HTTP 1.1 data.

I enabled HTTP 2.0 / SPDY in Chrome and visited https://http2.akamai.com to see the request and response.

Comment: Off topic, tool recommendation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wireshark has support for HTTP/2.0 (https://wiki.wireshark.org/HTTP2)

You can also simply check the frames using the built-in Chrome packet monitor.

Open a tab to chrome://net-internals, select 'SPDY' (or 'HTTP/2' in most recent versions) in the top left menu and click 'View live SPDY sessions' or 'View live HTTP/2 sessions'.

Whenever another tab is using a new SPDY or HTTP/2 connection, you'll be able to inspect the stream details from this tab.

Comment: SPDY seems to have been replaced by/renamed to HTTP/2 in the latest Chrome.